# How to Revert to Previous State on Manga App?

Tags: icloud, backup, restore

I was on a manga app (Manga Reader - Manga Viewer by Yubo Wang) when I had accidentally pressed the ‘Restore’ button, which uses an iCloud backup to restore your ‘favourites’ and reading history. My last backup was from 2+ years ago, and I was wondering if there is anyway to get the app back to the state it was at a week ago. Currently I’m trying through iMazing, which, while I don’t have a backup on it I have been able to access the app’s Logs, though I honestly don’t know how to make heads or tails of those. Is it possible to somehow revert the ‘restore’?

Comment: If the restore overwrote the existing favourites/history and you don't have any copy of the overwritten data any longer, you will be out of luck.